# Flink Streaming XML to JDBC

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am fairly new to Flink and I am currently trying to build a Data Pipeline which takes an XML Document from a Kafka Topic and write it into a Relational database.

**POJO**

```
public class MyClass{
public String firstAttribute;
public String secondAttribute;
public List<Item> items;

public MyClass(){}
}
public String generateSqlString(String tableName){
   ...
   return sqlString;
}


public class Item{
public String name;
public String value;
public String type;

public Item(){}
}
```

**Streaming App**

```
StreamingExecutionEnvironment env = StreamingExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
...
FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(consumerTopic,new SimpleStringSchema(),consumerProperties);
DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(consumer);
DataStreamSink<MyClass> myClassStream = stream
.map(new ParseJsonMapFunction())
.addSink(JdbcSink.sink(
                      ??.generateSqlString(tableName), // At this point i want to access the instance of MyClass to 
                      (ps,t)->{
                      ps.setString(1,t.firstAttribute);
                      ps.setString(2,t.secondAttribute);
                      int counter = 3;
                      for(Item item : t.items){
                         ps.setObject(counter,item.name);
                         counter++;
                         ps.setObject(counter,item.value);
                         counter++;
                         ps.setObject(counter,item.type);
                         counter++;
                      }
                      },
                      new JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                        .withUrl(url)
                        .withDriverName(driverName)
                        .withUserName(user)
                        .withPassword(password)
                        .build()));
env.execute("Flink Streaming Sample");
```

My problem is that i don't know how i can access the instance of MyClass to call the function generateSqlString.